# Tax calculator only printing the original input and not the total

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a VERY simple tax calculator to test my learning of Python, and it's only printing the original input and not the result.

I tried messing with the variables - I was getting errors and realized it's because I define the original variable outside of the function, but not sure what else to try.

```
import math

def tax(s):
  s = input("What is the bill?")
  tax_added = s * .07
  total = s + tax_added
  print(total)
```

I expect a total with tax added, but I just get the result of S.

Comment: do you expect your input to be a float?

Comment: How do you call your function? why do you provide `s` as parameter and fill it with the string gathered by `input(...)`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not converting the result of your input which is a string into a float (I assume you expect your input to be a float).

```
import math

def tax(s):
  s = float(input("What is the bill?"))
  tax_added = s * .07
  total = s + tax_added
  print(total)
```

One observation, why are you taking `s` as parameter if you are going to replace it with your input? I mean, you can get rid of it.

Based on what I have stated:

```
def tax():
    s = float(input("What is the bill?"))
    tax_added = s * .07
    total = s + tax_added
    print(total)
```

#### Example

```
>>> tax()
What is the bill?10
10.7
```

Comment: I converted it to a float, and I'm still just getting the original input with no additions.

Comment: @JohnAllison, that is very weird, how are you calling the function?

Comment: @JohnAllison, would you mind checking my updated answer, and let me know if this works. I personally did, and it does.

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function gives you string:

```
 s = input("What is the bill?")
```

If you want that to be a number, cast it:

```
s = float(input("What is the bill?"))
```